# Property is private and only accessible within class error in Angular Library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot, angular-library

I am trying to convert an Angular 6 application in a reusable library; here is what I did:

- created a new Angular workspace
- created a new Angular library project inside that workspace
- copied the artifacts from the old application inside the library and adjusted the import statements

When I try to compile the project with "ng build --project=.." I get a lot of these errors:
"Property X is private and only accessible within class Y"

I understand the errors and I will correct them but my question is:
If I try to build the old application with aot I don't get this error..why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the AOT compile, Angular statically analyzes your code. Using wrong access modifiers is a criteria that lets the AOT compile fail, while the compile succeeds in a build without AOT.

This is the way it is because in the "just in time" mode (which usually is your ng start), Typescript is not being used - ES5 code is being generated, so there's no such concept as a "private" field, and we have no way of enforcing this.

Things that are accessed from a template must be public, since they're being accessed outside of the class instance.

Comment: Yes, but compiling the original app with AOT enabled doesn't raise any error, while compiling the library does raise the error..so I thought there should be another reason..

Comment: Have you tried a "prod build": `ng build --prod". Usually, the default angular project generated with angular cli has different build settings when you look at the prod environment in your angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The `private` property is working with specific versions of Typescript.
When creating your new Angular workspace, a new typescript version was installed.

Comment: The difference is JiT mode uses Typescript, AOT uses ES5. Please see my answer