# Migrated application to Angular 6 : But getting errors while running npm run build --prod. But command npm run build --env=prod runs successfully

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

When I Use command  **npm run build -- --prod** I get following error messages :

- Property 'PropertyName1' is private and only accessible within class 'AppComponent'
- Property 'PropertyName2' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

> ERROR in src\app\components\app\app.component.html(77,56): : Property
>   'validate' is private and only accessible within class 'AppComponent'.
>       src\app\components\entitysearchlight\entitysearchlight.component.html(3,157):
>   : Property 'loadingMessage' is private and only accessible within
>   class 'EntitySearchLightComponent'.
>       src\app\components\entitysearchlight\entitysearchlight.component.html(23,91):
>   : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>       src\app\components\entitysearchlight\entitysearchlight.component.html(97,62):
>   : Property 'e' does not exist on type 'EntitySearchLightComponent'.
>       src\app\components\search\search.component.html(3,157): : Property 'loadingMessage' is private and only accessible within class
>   'SearchComponent'.
>       src\app\components\search\search.component.html(23,91): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>       src\app\components\search\search.component.html(57,43): : Property 'onFilterItemSelect' is private and only accessible within class
>   'SearchComponent'.
>       src\app\components\search\search.component.html(90,58): : Property 'e' does not exist on type 'SearchComponent'.

Same application builds successfully when i run : **npm run build --env=prod**

Can you please let me know how build process or configuration changes due to these two commands ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property is private and only accessible within class error in Angular Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330599/property-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-error-in-angular-library)

Comment: If you created models (exporting a class), and set the properties as for example: private name: string; this error could pop up, change to public

Comment: @JulienAmbos Thanks for link but can you please explain the difference in terms of build process ?

Comment: @NemanjaG Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was written above you need change access modificator `private` to `public`. You have a little files where is necessary. However, you need to avoid the problem in feature.

i recommended use tslint and check you code. Add in `tslint.json` new rule

```
"rules": {
...
    "member-access": true,
```

and everywhere add access modificator.

Create command in `package.json` where you can check build

```
 "scripts": {
    "lint": "ng lint",
     ...
    "building:prod": "npm i && ng lint && ng build --prod"
  },
```

Comment: It is not throwing error on local. any additional configuration required

Comment: `local` you mean `ng serve`?

Comment: no i am using Angualr 6 .net core SPA template project type

Comment: I not sure  right your understood. You truing create local build run `npm run building:prod` with some lint error, and have not error, didn't it?

Comment: The error is fixed which was coming while deployment of the application. But same error does not appears on local even if i set member-access : true in tslint.json

Comment: you truing build from Visual Studio ?

Comment: yes i am building in visual studio as i am using .net core Angular SPA template project type

Comment: 1 make sure that you have [tslint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) in VS. 2 tslinter have been setting on your file from tslint.json in you project (`Tools > Web Code Analysis > Edit TSLint Settings (tslint.json)`)

Comment: Truing open Console from VS go to you project directory and call `ng lint`. Do you have any errors?

Comment: i have used https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RichNewman.TypeScriptAnalyzer to get the error while building on local

Comment: Can you edit tslint settings and choose tslint.json from your project? Will any error?

Answer (score 1):

When you run compile with --prod switch, in Angular 6 default is AOT (compile ahead of time of template components) and change is that props from component class (ts files) that are used in template (HTML file or HTML template inside component) must be public:

remove private or protected from validate,
remove private or protected from loadingMessage, 
...

in components ts file.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

When you take a look into `angular.json` you will see that there are some more options you can set for the `npm run build --prod` flag but when you run the `npm run build --env=prod` you have just simply changed the `environment.ts` file so that options won't be used here.

**Environment.ts**

In folder `environment` you can find two files (by default) one is used for production and second should be used locally. By running `npm run build --env=prod` you just build your app with the `environment.prod.ts` but with the default `ng build` not `ng build --prod`.

In code you can use environment to register some modules only with production build and not with the local config.

Example:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
```

Comment: What do mean by changing Environment ts file?

Answer (score 1):

The `--prod` flag activate many optimization flag. One of them is `--aot` for Ahead Of Time compilation. Your component templates are compiled during the build, so TypeScript can detect more issue in your code. You can compile in dev mode but still activate the `--aot` flag if you want to see this error before building for prod.

**From [the official compiler documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)**

> Detect template errors earlier
>
> The AOT compiler detects and reports template binding errors during the build step before users can see them.